# WCF: The socket connection was aborted

Tags: c#, wcf, service

```
CommunicationException was unhandled by user code
The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message
or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource
issue. Local socket timeout was '02:48:04.9840000'.
```

I've been testing this application for months and have just seen this error after making a small change to one of the services.  It's only a few seconds, so I don't think it's a timeout issue.

InnerException: System.IO.IOException : The read operation failed, see inner exception

(Inner) InnerException: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.

Any suggestions are greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suggest you investigate why did the remote host close the connection.

Comment: Well, when I debug through it, everything seems to be fine but when returning from the manager to the proxy (client), the exception is thrown.  I wanna say more data is coming through that is allowed, but no more than the usual is coming through

Comment: Did you try WCF tracing?

Comment: Can you recommend a good resource for this Ladislav?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are most likely running into quota issues like the MaxReceivedMessageSize, MaxArrayLength, MaxStringContentLength defined in the binding.

You can also have a look at the MaxItemsInObjectGraph attribute available in the behaviors.

Answer (score 9):

Typically I have seen this error when the opposite party does not cleanly shut down the connection.  If on the client side you have a class that inherits from `ClientBase<T>` then you should call `Close` when you are finished with the service (actually `ClientBase<T>` implements `IDisposable` so you can use a `using` statement).

If you are using a `ChannelFactory<T>` to create the connection to the service the result is a proxy that implements the contract but also implements `ICommunicationObject`; you should call `Close` on this when you are finished.

On the service side things are not the same, the session (and therefore the underlying socket) is managed by the client.  If the service is dropping the socket most likely this is the result of an error, in which case Music Magi's suggestion is a good one. Microsoft talks about how to go about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx).

Note that to get a clear picture of what is going on you may have to set up tracing for both the client and the service.  In order to view the traces you would use `SvcTraceViewer` which should be in the `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin` or `Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\bin` folder.  If you have to trace both the client and the service you can open both files together in `SvcTraceViewer` using the `File / Add` menu.

Answer (score 3):

I experienced some socket connection aborted for different reasons that I feel is worth an answer.

In addition to not having high enough values in your MaxReceivedMessageSize, MaxArrayLength, MaxStringContentLength, MaxItemsInObjectGraph as Johann pointed out...

Check to make sure the types that you're serializing play nicely with WCF. For example, I was having the same problem but then realized that I was sending `System.DBNull` over the wire which caused the service to abort. Once I filtered the `DBNull` objects out, things started working again.

Answer (score 2):

In my case, there was an enum added to the response object but the stored procedure used to populate the object was not returning the value from the database. It was returning its default value (which is zero) which is not a valid value for the enum that was created. As an example :

```
using System;

namespace Playground
{
    internal class Program
    {
        private static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine((int)new SomeResponse().Enum);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public enum SomeEnum
        {
            Value1 = 1,
            Value2 = 2,
            Value3 = 3
        }

        public class SomeResponse
        {
            public SomeEnum Enum { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

You will see that the value of the enum is zero, even though there is no enum value of zero.

If you try to return the SomeResponse object from a WCF call and it has this state, you end up getting the same error as stated in the question.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was returning a Stream with a using clause on the stream. That closed the stream before it was sent and created the connection aborted error.

Answer (score 0):

In my case we have two systems - the `remoteSystem` and the `clientSystem`

- Both systems have their public/private certificates for authentication.
- Each system has it's own private key, and the public key of it's peer.
- The client authenticates itself with the `dev.clientSubsystem.acme` cert

At first the firewall was suspected but this was eliminated by testing with

```
Test-NetConnection -Port 808 -ComputerName dev.remote-system.acme-corp.net-InformationLevel Detailed
```

It turned out this error was when the clientSystem is configured to authenticate with it's private held certificate (`dev.clientSubsystem.acme`) but the certificate doesn't exist - or in our case was referencing the wrong certificate for authentication.

```
<system.serviceModel>
   <client>
      <endpoint name="RemoteSystemService" address="net.tcp://dev.remote-system.acme-corp.net:808/service.svc" behaviorConfiguration="remoteSystemNetTcpBindingBehavior" binding="netTcpBinding" contract="AcmeCorp.RemoteSystem.IRemoteSystemService">
         <identity>
            <dns value="dev.remote-system.acme" />
         </identity>
      </endpoint>
   </client>
   <bindings>
      <netTcpBinding>
         <binding>
            <security mode="Transport">
               <transport clientCredentialType="Certificate" protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
            </security>
         </binding>
      </netTcpBinding>
   </bindings>
   <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
         <behavior name="remoteSystemNetTcpBindingBehavior">
            <clientCredentials>
               <clientCertificate findValue="CN=dev.clientSubsystem.acme" storeLocation="LocalMachine" storeName="My" x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
               <serviceCertificate>
                  <authentication certificateValidationMode="PeerTrust" />
               </serviceCertificate>
            </clientCredentials>
         </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
</system.serviceModel>
```