# Error in WCF when hosting on different machine

Tags: wcf, nettcpbinding

I have developed a `WCF` service hosted on a `windows service` to access my database.

I have another `WCF` service which will call the previous WCF service. That is also hosted on a windows service.

Both are woking fine. Next I move my first `wcf` to another machine. Now it is not working. It gives following exception.

> The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:29:59.9687510'.

I am using `netTcpBinding`.

This same issue has asked several times on SO. But non of them fix my isse.
Please advice me.

Answer (score 1):

its most likely the timeout settings, hope this will help

[WCF Windows Service TimeOut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919287/wcf-windows-service-timeout)

[WCF: The socket connection was aborted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990661/wcf-the-socket-connection-was-aborted)

http://www.darkside.co.za/archive/2008/08/01/wcf-error-caused-by-a-serialisation-issue.aspx